# How many internet users can an ISP assign to a single IP address?

Tags: ip, isp

It’s hard to believe that an IP address is reserved for only one internet user.

Many internet service providers (ISPs) have to cater to several *mobile* Wi-Fi home subscribers in the same geographic area, so aren’t they assigning several customers to each IP address they own rather than one?

Comment: There is no answer to your question. A small business with 100 or more people can have one external IP address. 2 persons in a residence can have one external IP address.  How long is a piece of string?

Comment: ok so an IP address is not uniquely assigned to any one individual. meaning that tracking someone to their doorstep by their IP address is a myth

Comment: it's often assigned to a physical device, so tracking to the address where the router is is entirely possible. you won't know which individual at that address.

Comment: When many users get an IP address it's called CGNAT. They try to avoid it, but they have no choice any more.

Comment: While I already [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1621845/167207), can you perhaps explain what you are concerned about? This all feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) where you want to know what is the one key thing that can identify you online. The reality is an IP address alone won’t expose you to the risk of one person know your IP address. But your ISP knows tons more about you… Including your billing address. And if law enforcement is empowered to investigate you, all bets are off.

Comment: And since the original poster did not clarify this very leading question, instead they [posted a whole new question](https://superuser.com/q/1621921/167207) — that is now closed — with the stated desire of trying to extract another Telegram user’s IP address to “prove” they are a scammer. You know what? Stop engaging in fights with scammers. Attempting “prove” they are liars won’t change a scammer from being a scammer. Just ignore and block them and move on. In the context of your desire this question is really misleading.

Comment: as said, this question has nothing to do with Telegram, and your link is to a question that was never even thought up until half an hour ago. Sure let's ignore scammers while hundreds of others are getting scammed by them. too bad we can't ignore people who *way over*-connect the dots. The question here reduces to the fact that the ISP knows the most about an IP address user, while the other question reduces to my guess that the proprietary software company knows the most about their software users' IP addresses, and will likely protect the identities of users harming others on their app

Comment: @user610620 Neither of your questions show goodwill towards the questions asked. In fact — as I have said [in a comment above](https://superuser.com/questions/1621681/how-many-internet-users-can-an-isp-assign-to-a-single-ip-address#comment2475165_1621681) — the these questions are all [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) where you are asking one thing but are not asking the core question. The reality is this questions should be closed as well since it is so open-ended because your question is so vague. That is not what this site is about.

Comment: how is "How many internet users can an ISP assign to a single IP address?" vague? I think it's a good question I wondered for years, albeit general, and now I'm punished for it just because you chose to associate it with a completely different unrelated question? I can forgive you closing the other one, but based on the huge turn-out here, I think you would be forfeiting alot of other people's work, besides your own which I was about to mark best answer before you went ape

Comment: you've even contradicted yourself, because your answer at the very bottom of this page (which I was going to mark best answer) even identifies  and re-iterates the "core question" *in* my question as a *blockquote*, yet you're here in the comments talking about  me "not asking the core question". what?

Comment: _"ok so an IP address is not uniquely assigned to any one individual."_ - Whoa, nobody said that. Don't jump to conclusions like that.

Comment: i know, someone clarified it in one of the answers below afterwards

Comment: Technically, its possible to assign every customer they have to a single IP.

Comment: "It’s hard to believe that an IP address is reserved for only one internet user." - a static IPv4 address is standard with the Internet connection plan I have with the ISP serving my home. Most of the time there is only one Internet user here, unless you count the cat occasionally taking an interest in what I'm playing on Netflix. In fact I also have a block of 8, 6 publicly useable, routed down the same line, though that is less standard especially these days (I've had them allocated for years).

Comment: The way the question is phrased is hard to answer.  Can you clarify what your actual question is please?  You seem confused.  Is it how many users, or how/why does it work?

Answer (score 18):

I'll focus on this comment you made:

> tracking someone to their doorstep by their IP address is a myth

No, not a myth at all.

In most cases, especially for wired connections, **each Internet connection (your DSL, cable or fibre connection) will have one distinct IP address**. It may be **fixed** (you get assigned an IP address when your connection is first set up), in which cases mapping an IP to an exact subscriber and their address is trivial, or **dynamic** (changing every day or week or whatever), in which case you need to pieces of information: the IP and the date/time. The ISP will keep records of which IP was assigned to who, and can respond to request from the competent authorities.

In both cases, **this will point to a connection (router)**: beyond that, home or office networks usually use NAT, so there may be many computers sharing the same (public, external) IP, but it will definitely have brought the police to the doorstep.

In some cases, especially for mobile networks, but also for some fixed networks, the ISP/carrier needs a lot more IP addresses than they have. In that case, they have to use **CGNAT (Carrier-grade NAT)**, which means **the same IP can be used for many different customers**. In this case, one will need one additional piece of information: the source port number used in the incriminated TCP or UDP connections.

**With the combination of IP + date/time + source port, the ISP should be able to map that to the relevant subscriber**. To simplify things, some ISPs will just split the available port range (1024-65536) between connections, for instance the first 10 000 for customer 1, the next 10 000 for customer 2, etc, but it's really up to them how they handle things.

In this case, for fixed networks, it will again point to a specific connection. In the case of mobile networks, it will point to a specific terminal (phone, tablet, mobile Wi-Fi hotspot...) which can be a lot more precise in terms of the specific user.

**So in all cases, if you have IP + date/time + source port, yes, you can find the specific connection used, and either a location (for fixed connections) or a terminal (for mobile).**

But remember that's only the first step. After that, the authorities could examine your devices for evidence, of which there is generally plenty.

In short: don't do anything bad, they **will** find you.

Comment: ...if they want to.

Comment: What is needed: Date + time + timezone + IP address, for the non Carrier Grade NAT. For GCN, Date + time + timezone + IP address + protocol + port number. Plus maybe some luck with smaller ISPs as they may not have figured out how to (or that they need to) log each connection initiation. And the legal authority to force or at least convince the ISP to turn it over.

Comment: In short, use TOR. (And don't do anything bad anyway. Right?)

Comment: FWIW, the original poster is really dancing around their goal; proving a Telegram user is not who they are based on IP address. An IP address they don’t even have but they want to “prove” something. Read my [comment to the original question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1621681/how-many-internet-users-can-an-isp-assign-to-a-single-ip-address#comment2475186_1621681).

Comment: How would an ISP ever be placed in a situation where they would have more customers than IPs?  There are many many many orders of magnitude more possible IPv6 addresses than there are people on Earth, and even if each person has multiple Internet-connected devices, each connected through several network cards, it should still be no trouble at all for an ISP to always make sure that it has many more available IPs than it has customers.

Comment: @Sean Of course we are talking about IPv4 addresses here, which I believe are still the only option in many, many cases.

Comment: Good answer here. To add some fuel to the fire, it's entirely possible for someone to present an entirely untraceable, nearly random address by using gateways.  And there are gateways (e.g. TOR) that are designed to NOT leave a trace of who the originator actually is.

I *HAVE* successfully sued telemarketers (and prevailed in US courts) by tracing telemarketer IP addresses - but not in the direct way the OP imagines.  In one case I was not only able to identify the scammer by his static IP, but also the scammer's ATTORNEY!

Answer (score 9):

> It's hard to believe that an IP address is reserved for only one internet user. [...][Aren't ISPs] assigning several customers to each IP address they own rather than one?

Sometimes, but not always.

With [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), there are currently two different numbering systems, [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). IPv4 addresses (`0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`) are 32 bit numbers and are limited to about 2<sup>32</sup> (4,294,967,296) total addresses, leading to the phenomenon of [IP address exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion). However, this limitation on IPv4 addresses has been known since the 1980s and thus IPv6 addresses (128 bit numbers i.e. 2<sup>128</sup> or 340 trillion trillion trillion possible addresses) were introduced as a superseding system.

As I understand it, regarding the actual implementation and assignment of IPv4 addresses, there are two potential scenarios:

- An ISP assigns one customer an IPv4 address, assuming they "own" enough of these addresses to do so.
- An ISP uses [Carrier-grade Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) to provide a public IPv4 address used by multiple customers and then sort any communications out internally.

Regarding mobile network providers, they often use CGNAT as far as I am aware. That said, assuming IPv6 was more commonly adopted (and it will be in the future), assigning individual IPv6 addresses to every single user device would be trivial.

> An IP address is not uniquely assigned to any one individual, meaning that tracking someone to their doorstep by their IP address is a myth.

ISPs can absolutely keep records of which customers were using an IP at any given time and those records can (potentially) make their way into the hands of other entities (e.g. law enforcement, lawyers, hackers, etc.).

Comment: 'and it will be in the future' people have been saying this for 20 years now. It’s still almost impossible in many parts of the world to actually get IPv6 access without renting a VPS and configuring your system to tunnel through that, and there is still no evidence that most of the major ISPs actually care at all about it unless their major business customers actively complain.

Comment: what other computer- or connection-based information would tip off 'other entities' better than deductively narrowing down someone's IP address to a geolocation?

Comment: @J... No, the problem very much does exist. NAT (even CGN) is _not_ a proper solution, and is completely useless for a lot of applications. Even aside from that though, there are practical benefits to using IPv6 other than global IPv4 address exhaustion. It’s much easier to write a compliant IPv6 implementation than IPv4 (and can be done with much less code), you get a much larger private address space (both of these are significant points for IoT), and you get support for packets larger than 64k (this is significant for short local P2P links as well as VPN protocols).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn what do you mean NAT isn’t a proper solution? It’s been a solution for the last 20+ years! You might not like it, or think it’s the best solution, but it works just fine for anyone with more than one internet connected device on their home network!

Comment: @Tim NAT is a viable option for (most) client systems, but is completely useless for many server setups. Even the ISPs know this, as one of the big distinguishing factors for ‘commercial’ or ‘business’ plans is that you get more than just one address and aren’t behind any NAT router.

Answer (score 7):

It's often assigned to a physical device, so tracking to an address where the router is is entirely possible. You won't know which individual at that address.

But then there's [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) so it's not always possible.

Comment: what if there's no physical router near any of the subscribers using the network. instead they are connecting to an ISP/mobile carrier wifi, which i don't think constitutes a physical router at least locally, since the IP address gives a geolocation in a city 30 miles away, despite the subscriber being based in the next largest city over

Comment: @user610620 Something still has that IP address... Geolocation might list it in a specific city or place, but your ISP will assign that to a device's MAC address, most likely the router, which can easily have it's location determined and you are likely within 100' of the router or AP that is providing the WiFi service. Even if geolocation says your in X place, your ISP knows where it is located and could disclose to authorities if the correct conditions are met.

Comment: what is AP. and what are the alternatives to routers given the current state of cloud/wifi  internet

Comment: FWIW, the original poster is really dancing around their goal; proving a Telegram user is not who they are based on IP address. An IP address they don’t even have but they want to “prove” something. Read my [comment to the original question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1621681/how-many-internet-users-can-an-isp-assign-to-a-single-ip-address#comment2475186_1621681).

Answer (score 6):

IP addresses are assigned to devices (not people):

**(a) Routers** (for almost any size of network from 1 or 2 up to hundreds of devices (small business). Home users (1 IP) can be tracked but not necessarily the individual therein if numerous individuals

Depending on the home setups and the way ISPs do things in different countries, homes may have 1 IP (I do) or they may share a service (multiple residences on 1 IP).

And:

**(b) individual devices (smart phones** and some appliances) which has resulted in the need for IPv6 addressing. Smart phones can normally be tracked.

So tracking people is not a myth, but it is normally the authorities doing the tracking.

There is certainly no unique answer to your question:  1 device and up - pick your business size limit.

(c) some multiple dwelling residences may (or may not) have one IP address. Depends on ISP and Country.

Much variability.

Comment: multiple dwelling residences could have 8 different families, each whose ISP is a different mobile carrier (mobile + home internet is bundled together nowadays) since they never subscribed to a plan together. The probability would be very low that any of them even share the same IP address despite being in the identical geolocation. what then

Comment: That is just the way it is. It all depends on the specific connections as to who can be traced. Authorities can always trace to an IP address if they put enough effort in it.

Comment: when you say "Smart phones can normally be tracked", which I take to say "*are* normally tracked", are you implying that phone-users on an IP address are no less trackable than landline internet connectors? that they have no privacy advantage over fixed connections? I thought the mobility of the smart phone suggests it hops IP addresses throughout the day, while commuting in and out of the home city, whereas land connections are dormant, fixed in one place?

Comment: A smart phone has an IP and one user. This can be tracked. A landline internet IP can be tracked, but if multiple users, the authorities do not know who.

Comment: FWIW, the original poster is really dancing around their goal; proving a Telegram user is not who they are based on IP address. An IP address they don’t even have but they want to “prove” something. Read my [comment to the original question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1621681/how-many-internet-users-can-an-isp-assign-to-a-single-ip-address#comment2475186_1621681).

Answer (score 6):

With respect of IPv6 addresses, whole ranges can be set aside per user.  IPV6 address space is unbelievably large.

For the more common IPV4 space -

IP addresses are associated with devices rather then users.   As a single SOHO router supports a number of users behind an IP address with NAT, so to can this be done at a carrier level using Carrier Grade NAT (this is popular on mobile networks and countries - mainly developing countries which joined the Internet en-mass later.

**There is a limit to the number of users that can share an IP address, but the number is pretty large**.   In order to use NAT 4 pieces of information are needed - the source address, source port, destination address and destination port.  A port has a number between 0 and 65535.  Destination ports and IP addresses are defined by the service.   This is slightly technically inaccurate, but If we make a first approximation that everyone needs to be able to access the target address [ eg www.google.com or netflix or another very popular property ] this means that the number of users that can share the address is limited by the source ports - so 65535.  There are further restrictions on this - because of simultaneous requests coming from a browser / user, and because of the effects of port tracking on routers, so in practice the number of users that share a single IP address is a lot less then that.    (Also, ports less then 1024 have a special meaning)

Answer (score 3):

### The way physical ISP connections work is 100% different than how Wi-Fi ISP connections work.

#### And a lot of this also depends on the business requirement policies for ISPs themselves; some are strict and some are not.

A lot of answers here, but I wanted to post this to focus on the core of your question:

> “Many internet service providers (ISPs) have to cater to several *mobile* Wi-Fi home subscribers in the same geographic area, so aren’t they assigning several customers to each IP address they own rather than one?”

In the case of mobile Wi-Fi provided by an ISP that account is managed *purely* by account credentials and not your device. And unless you go out of your way to request a static IP address for a Wi-Fi account, you can assume that the IP address you get from a Wi-Fi connection is just random and based on what IP address is available from your ISP

And I think that is what is mucking up your understanding of this.

More succinctly here is a summary:

- **Wired ISP Connection**: Access and IP address assignment is often associated to your modem’s MAC address and *possibly* — in some cases — account credentials. In some cases the ISP doesn’t care about the MAC address of the device but grants access based just on user credentials. But in most cases assume the device for a physical, wired connection are tied to the MAC address of the device.
- **Wireless ISP Connection**: Access and IP address assignment is *always* associated to account credentials. So IP addresses don’t usually follow that account as they walk around the world. I say *usually* because some ISPs do offer static IP addresses for mobile-only accounts. But that is not the norm.

So when you say:

> “It’s hard to believe that an IP address is reserved for only one internet user.”

You are 100% right. The standard expectation is that when you connect to your ISP is your IP address will be inconsistent; you will get whatever IP address the ISP assigns to you. You might have an ISP that simply assigns addresses based on what address is unused in a pool of addresses. Or your ISP can assign you the same address each time you cycle your modem. But unless you are explicitly requesting your ISP assign you a static IP address, nothing is guaranteed.

#### An IP address alone is not enough to track someone, but is often a valuable piece of data to use to narrow down where someone is located.

And in a comment you state this:

> “OK… So an IP address is not uniquely assigned to any one individual. Meaning that tracking someone to their doorstep by their IP address is a myth.”

Not 100% a myth and all depends on who is the one tracking you and how deep their access is to your ISPs access logs and — honestly — where you are located

Assuming you are just a 100% nobody who has an IP address for someone, you could *possibly* geolocate them. I say possibly because it all depends on many factors:

- **Sparsely Populated Areas**: If you are in a sparsely populated area — a rural area outside of the cities — that has Internet service and that service has an IP address that can be geolocated, you are easy to identify. I mean if you only have a few neighbors and live in single family homes with one ISP connection to each home, the chances of you being identified is quite high.
- **Densely Populated Areas**: The chances of your IP address being connected directly to you via geolocation are slim at best. Because one single geolocated area can have dozens — possibly hundreds — of Internet users in a city. So someone might be able to figure out the general neighborhood the IP address is associated with but that’s that.

Now if somehow someone has access to the ISP logs, all bets are off. You account will be tied to whatever IP address you use and that account has an address and then you are successfully identified.

Comment: thanks for focusing on the question about wifi IP addresses. any reason why mobile subscribers might be given an IP address that, despite being randomized daily, is consistently geolocated in another larger city in the same country 40 miles away? The user, for example, might live in Philadelphia, but the IP address (assigned by their mobile ISP) is always showing as being geolocated in NYC. Wouldn't this (unintentionally) throw a tracker off big time?

Comment: @user610620 I think that falls under the the umbrella of the ISP not guaranteeing anything for dynamically assigned IPs. Meaning — that unless you pay for it or the ISP chooses to do it — nothing about your assigned IP address is guaranteed past you having a connection. The fact is IP address blocks are bought and sold and shifted at will. So perhaps — for example — T-Mobile buys Sprint. Sprint’s IP addresses are connected to a router in Brooklyn, NY. But T-Mobile decides to shift those IPs to Queens, NY. Geolocation is off until that is corrected and that is not really important to T-Mobile.

Comment: PS: “Wouldn't this (unintentionally) throw a tracker off big time?” Yes, this happens. Check any GeoLocation tracker and see that is never really accurate. That is why strictly geolocating based on IP address is not ever really that accurate. Like the reason why companies like Google and Facebook can sell geolocated adds is they collect data on your phone’s GPS location and track via HTML5 Canvas fingerprinting on top of an IP address.

Comment: what piece of serial/computer information can tip off trackers better than someone's IP address?

Comment: @user610620 It’s not one thing and not ever one formula.

Comment: assuming IP address is at the top of the list for identifying internet users, what are the next best things/formulas to accompany it

Comment: @user610620 I am sorry, but I know what I know and I posted what I posted. I will be posting a comment on your question requesting you better focus your question. The reality is it all depends on context: One lone person online will know not much about your location past broad specifics with just an IP address. And that is best case for the person. But an ISP knows more and law enforcement knows even more *if they have a legal right to connect all the dots*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on when you're talking about.

In the early days of the internet (i.e. pre-1994), every individual *device* would have its own, unique, publicly accessible IP address. It would get that address either when it connected/powered on/whatever, or it would be programmed into the device. It was much like how each mailbox would have its own mail address.

Unfortunately, with the rapid expansion of technology, the internet [began running out of IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion). So, in 1994, the idea of [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) as a stop-gap measure to try and conserve IP addresses. In this scheme*, each device in a building (or whatever) would receive a *private* IP address, which couldn't be routed over the public internet, for communication amongst each other. Since the addresses were private, the same address could be allocated to multiple devices, just so long as those devices weren't on the same network. In order to actually communicate to the internet at large, a router would sit between the private network and public internet, translating between its assigned public address and private addresses on the fly.

As IP addresses continue to become more scarce, some ISPs have started implementing NAT at the regional level. As in, you get a private IP from your ISP rather than a public one, and the ISP can then handle a group of people under one publicly-accessible IP.

Do remember, though, that NAT was intended only as a stop-gap measure. The "real" solution, officially adopted in 1995, is [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). IPv6 expands the number of available IP addresses to an absolutely ridiculously huge number. Thus, under IPv6, the internet would go back to the original setup of one IP address per device. Unfortunately, even over two decades later, less than 35% of internet traffic uses IPv6 according to Google. But that number is going up.

*Note that I'm only describing NAT as it is typically used to reduce IP address congestion. There are many other uses for NAT that are outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since ISPs cannot know how many people live in a household or work in the same office, I'm gonna rephrase your question as:

> How many **customers** can an ISP assign to a single IP address?

And the answer to that question is:

## One.

The reasoning for this is that **ISPs need to uniquely identify each customer to route** (IP) **traffic to each of them**.

ISPs *might* assign/allocate more than one IP address per customer. A typical use case is ISPs grouping several services through the same router device and phisical cabling - in other words, internet access plus telephony plus TV. ISPs with this kind of offerings can leverage [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN)s to [mux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) 3 different IP addresses to the same customer.

Don't think of household routers/gateways (or [customer-premises equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer-premises_equipment)) as hardware devices with one IP address. Instead, think of them as devices with **3** (or more) addresses:

- One address for routing internet IP traffic to computers
- One address for performing [Voice-over-IP telephony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) (in which the household router might do the heavy lifting of audio encoding/decoding, and provide a RJ11 interface to which a [copper-loop POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) telephone can be connected)
- One address for [IPTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_television) services - for example, having a dedicated RJ45 jack for connecting a IPTV [set-top box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box).

It's important to keep in mind that **IP doesn't mean public Internet**. VoIP and IPTV networks are effectively closed LANs. It's safe to assume that these networks use addresses in the "private network" [IP blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Allocation) - 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x-172.31.x.x and 192.168.x.x

Specifically speaking about the IP address allocated for Internet IP traffic, since [Carrier-Grade Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) is a thing, the **IP address for internet IP traffic** might be:

- "Public", meaning it's not in any [special-use address block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses), and the allocation is handled by [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority), and it's (generally) accesible through the entire Internet.
- A CG-NAT address, in the 100.64.0.0/10 range
- A 10.x.x.x address (e.g. if the ISP uses NAT but not the CG-NAT specific address block)

With NAT/CG-NAT, **each customer** (or rather, their customer-premises device) **gets one and only one address**; but it might not be a *public* address.

So, since you might be interested in how many customers/devices might be "behind" the same "public" Internet IP address, I'm gonna rephrase your question again:

> How many **customer-premises devices** can an ISP **route traffic to, sharing the same** single **public Internet** IP**v4** address **for Internet-facing purposes**?

A reasonable answer to that is:

**Up to the size of a local network with CG-NAT addresses** (minus an extra router to actually handle CG-NAT) **, which equals 2^10**-3 **=**

## 1021 devices.

(Note that I'm only considering IPv4, leaving IPv6 and IPv4-to-IPv6 translation behind, and also note that ISPs *can* use more obscure/hackish/non-standard network configurations)